# Display multiple appointment details

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, web

I am creating a appointment booking system but at the moment I am having troubles to display multiple appointments. I am echoing only one appointment at the moment, my goal is for the user to view all of there appointments in a while or for loop. I am unsure of the correct style which is needed to display the values of the appointment for the second appointment etc. In my database there a many appointments needed to be viewed for the logged in user.

```
<?php 
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $sql = "SELECT
    points.appoint_date, 
    beauticians.b_firstname,
    users.username,
    service.service_name
  FROM points 
  INNER JOIN service ON service.service_id = service.service_id
  INNER JOIN beauticians ON beauticians.beautician_id = beauticians.beautician_id
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users.id";

  $query = $connect->query($sql);
  $result = $query->fetch_array();

  // close database connection
  $connect->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['username'] ?> </li>
  <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['b_firstname'] ?> </li>
  <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['service_name'] ?> </li>
  <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['appoint_date'] ?> </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: to add while loop to fetch each row of the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch each row of the result, and display it.

```
<?php 
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$sql = "SELECT 
    points.appoint_date, 
    beauticians.b_firstname, 
    users.username, 
    service.service_name
FROM points 
INNER JOIN service ON service.service_id = service.service_id
INNER JOIN beauticians ON beauticians.beautician_id = beauticians.beautician_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users.id";

$query = $connect->query($sql);

// close database connection
$connect->close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    while($result = $query->fetch_array()) {
?>
<ul>
    <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['username'] ?> </li>
    <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['b_firstname'] ?> </li>
    <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['service_name'] ?> </li>
    <li>Hello, <?php echo $result['appoint_date'] ?> </li>
</ul>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank u very much but the problem at the moment is that the result displays double the values.

Comment: The problem at the moment is that the result displays fine but it is displaying double the queries.

Comment: Edit your question, and show an example of the output. Also, run the query in phpAdmin and see what it shows. Does it show two (double) rows like your php script? If so, the query needs to be fixed. In that case, show the schema of the tables involved in your question.

Comment: Thank you sloan but this is the only one problem at the moment

Comment: If you want help, you have to supply the info needed, and do the tests asked. I understand the focus is on one problem, and there may be others.

Comment: can you tell me the query that is needed to be run

Comment: No. You refuse to supply the information needed to do that. Provide the request information, do the requested test in phpAdmin, and I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: A insert query into for this data as the test, forgive me im new to this

Comment: Read the comment above that starts with "Edit your question" that I made about 25 minutes ago. I won't respond any more until you have done that that comment asks you to do.

Comment: i ran the query but the problem still persist

Comment: I won't respond any more until you have done that that comment asks you to do.